# Tomcat needs to be restarted due to jasper reports

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper reports in my application for generating reports.
I have also provided the facility to download the reports in Pdf/Csv format.
But the problem I am facing is that, whenever I upload a new war file
(with or without the changes in the JRXML files used for designing the reports) I have to start/stop the tomcat server. Unless I do that, I am not able to generate the reports. There are no logs seen nothing happens and the 
reports are not generated as well. As soon as I restart the server, everything starts working like a charm. Reports get generated and everything else is fine. Why is this so? Why do I have to restart the server every time I upload a new war file? And this is a random behaviour.
Its not always necessary to restart the server the moment new war file is uploaded, it may be required to restart the server after some time.
(But it has to be restarted once in the new war's lifetime)
Is there any bug in Jasper reports regarding this behaviour?
How can I avoid this server-restart issue?

Comment: How the JRXML files are used? Post the code you use to generate reports from the JRXML. DO you compile them somehow?

Comment: yes I use ant to compile them.I use jenkins to create the war file and then I upload the war file to the server.

Comment: In my code I get the compiled JRXML files from the specified folder only. 
Even if I stop the server, upload the war and then start, reports may not be generated. Again the tomcat needs a restart and then everything starts working. This issue does not occur locally but is observed in production environment

Answer (score 0):

You can configure reloadable contexts in `server.xml` but it only monitors `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib`. If you want to re-deploy your webapp you can restart tomcat as you are doing or use tomcat manager